# Powershell hard crash on PIA event trigger

Tags: powershell, com, pia

Seeing a weird problem with powershell, here's the code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialname("Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint")
$ppt = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ppt -EventName "PresentationBeforeSave" -SourceIdentifier "LBPPTBeforeSave" -Action { Write-Host "here" }
```

I'm hooking into `PresentationBeforeSave` in PowerPoint. This registers fine, but when I hit save in Powerpoint ISE completely crashes. In event viewer I see bad stuff, exit code `80131506` and `0xc0000005`.

I can hook `SlideSelectionChanged` just fine though. So I'm wondering if this has something to do with the `Cancel` out variable that `PresentationBeforeSave` exposes? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Run it in powershell instead of ISE and see, ISE can cause issues that don’t exist in powershell console

Comment: Thanks but no change, crashed my console.